# How can we load large file from server on html page using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How can we load large file (say 1+ GB) from server on html page using AJAX?

I tried loading that big file on page, but that page is getting crashed.

JQuery code for loading content of file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        data : { 
           file_name : "show_1gb_file"
        },
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/_getFile'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        var html_text = "";
        html_text = '<li class="nav-item" id="' + data.file_name + '"> \
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" id="' + data.file_name + '" href="#' + data.file_name + '">' + data.file_name + '</a> \
                     </li>';
        $('#file-tab').append(html_text);
        $('#file-content').append('<div class="tab-pane active" id="' + data.file_name + '"><p>' + data.file_content + '</p></div>');
    });       
});
```

Comment: what is the file type, is it single file or zip file?

Comment: @Cocest: Its a single file and contains only text

Comment: how you are displaying it,, or downloading? check your console or network tab for ajax request and see the error, normally there is a limit  or the memory limit

Comment: @AhmedSunny: In network tab, its showing "DevTool was disconnected from page" and html page is showing "Something went wrong while displaying this web page"

Comment: i would seggust, load file in chunks, load 100mb or less by default, and when user cscroll down load next 100mb and so on,
same like pagination

Comment: @AhmedSunny: Yes it can be done but Cant we load a complete file instead of loading it in chunks?

Comment: Anyway, rendering of 1GB text will stuck the browser, can you please expand about your usages?

Comment: Don't load a 1 GB file into the browser. Think of a better way to solve the problem. What does the file contain?

Comment: @Tomalak: It basically contains logs in format : "timestamp : log details"

Comment: Yeah, I thought something like that. The normal way to solve this problem is to put all the logs into a database on the server and then write server-side code that lets the user pick a time range and only sends that time range to the client for display. Don't try to find a solution that is based on sending 1 GB data to the client. This is a waste of time, it will never work correctly.

Comment: @Prathamesh Raut: I think you should adhere to Tomalak idea. Load the text file in chunks based on time range. Maybe you should add description of what your about to achieve to receive help for implementation details.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks, will try to load it in chunks :)

Comment: That's absolutely not what I recommended. I said "write a server", not "load the file in chunks". But go ahead, it will be very educational.